# looping through and array object and creating an other object jquery js

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to create a `JSON` object such as

```
{
  "measure": camera_name,
  "interval_s": 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  "data": [
      [done_at, action],
      [done_at, action],
      [done_at, action]
  ]
}
```

my current object is an `array` from which I want to achieve the above one.
[image]

here is the situation: my array object has many objects as in picture am only showing one object, and there are going to be many logs in one object and I want to loop through this as well to set the in "data". the resulting json object will be something as

```
{
  "measure": camera_name,
  "interval_s": 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  "data": [
      [done_at, action],
      [done_at, action],
      [done_at, action]
  ]
},
{
  "measure": camera_name,
  "interval_s": 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
  "data": [
      [done_at, action],
      [done_at, action],
      [done_at, action]
  ]
}
```

How i can achieve that? I can loop through data but I have no idea how to store such json object. any help will be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ES6 is available to you, you can do this:

```
const result = data.map(entry => {
  return {
    measure: entry.camera_name,
    interval_s: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    data: entry.logs.map(log => {
      return [log.done_at, log.action]
    })
  }
})
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

Comment: and If its not available? and Even its not available to me. i need it js or jquery

Comment: Even i converted it to JS and then the results are empty array

Comment: You set your data to the "data" variable and the result was an empty array?

Comment: ES6 is a language specification for javascript, what I wrote above is valid JavaScript, no jQuery needed.

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/e6f6686ff9.png the above one is my object and lower ones is yours result. and it returning an array object no json

Comment: And even its empty